# Spring Batch: Implementing stop method in StoppableTasklets

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-framework-beans, spring-batch-tasklet

I am calling the following piece to stop the job.

```
Set<Long> executions = jobOperator.getRunningExecutions("Job-Builder");
jobOperator.stop(longExecutions.iterator().next());
```

The above method is stopping the job but Tasklets are still running. After reading through comments from stackoverflow I changed `tasklet` to use `StoppableTasklet` in my project so that I can stop them from running when I call the `joboperator.stop()`

My question here is that I am not sure how to identify if a job has been stopped and do necessary action inside the stop overriden method when I implement `StoppableTasklet`. Can you tell me on how I can do that in the overridden method?

Answer (score 0):

> My question here is that I am not sure how to identify if a job has been stopped and do necessary action inside the stop overriden method when I implement StoppableTasklet

You don't need to identify if the job has been stopped in your code. You need to implement the logic to stop the current tasklet and this logic will be called by the framework when you stop the job through `JobOperator#stop`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there sample code on how to stop the current tasklet?